# How to validate JSON with simplejson

Tags: python, django, json, simplejson

Occasionally I'm querying a server for JSON and receiving a 404 HTML page when the requested data is not available.

Thus, I must have a check to ensure that the JSON I'm expecting, is actually json rather than HTML.  I'm accomplishing this now by checking for a string that I can expect to be in the HTML is contained in the response, but I think there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Can you show us the code that's querying?

Comment: I'm confused.  It sounds like you want to validate in the browser, but simplejson is something you would use to validate on the server.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to tell that you recieved a 404, because the response code was not 200.  That is:

```
import urllib
resp = urllib.urlopen('http://example.com/')

if resp.getcode() == 200:
    rejoice()
if resp.getcode() == 404:
    sulk()
```

Comment: check for 404 was explicit just for illustration.  Actually, you should be checking for response >= 400, since any such value represents an error condition, and unless you know how to actually resolve specific errors, they should just be propagated up to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Find the first non-whitespace character. If it's "<" then you have HTML.

Also, check the content type header and HTTP status code.